# Least Squares Derivation

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, linear-algebra, total-least-squares

I come from physics and would like to derive the chi-square function given by the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/):

\begin{equation}
    \chi^2 (\boldsymbol\theta) = (\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol\mu(\boldsymbol \theta))^T V^{-1}(\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol\mu(\boldsymbol \theta)),
\end{equation}
with $V_{ij} = cov[y_i, y_j]$ being the covariance matrice, $\boldsymbol y = (y_1, \cdots, y_N)$ being the vector of measurements and $\boldsymbol \mu(\boldsymbol \theta)$ is the vector of predicted value.

My second question would be if the nomenclature **chisquare** and **least square** have the same meaning or are these two different methods?

---

So far I started with
\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{\hat y} = X \boldsymbol{\hat \beta}, \quad \text{with} \quad \boldsymbol{\hat y} = \pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\y_N}, \quad X=\pmatrix{1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1K} \\ 1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2K} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{N1} & x_{N2} & \cdots & x_{NK} }, \quad \boldsymbol{\hat \beta}=\pmatrix{\beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_K}
\end{equation}
and the hat (^) marking the estimators.

From here I defined my chisquared function to minimize:
\begin{equation}
  \chi^2 = (\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol{\hat y})^T (\boldsymbol y- \boldsymbol{\hat y}),
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol y$ represents the given data points and $\boldsymbol{\hat y}$ the theoretically predicted estimators. The above formular looks yet similar to the one I am looking for, apart from the fact that I do not know how to introduce the **inverse of the covariance matrix $V^{-1}$**.

I also previously derived the relations
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \boldsymbol{\hat \beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \boldsymbol{\hat y} \quad \text{and} \quad Var[\hat \beta] = \sigma(X^T X)^{-1},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where I am also insecure that the approximations made to obtain the ladder identity hold true in my case.

Comment: Good question. A GOOD beginning . Welcome to the site.

Comment: For anybody deeper interested in the topic I figured out the terminology of the above formula. It is refered to as: **Generalized Least Squares (GLS)**

Comment: @subhashc.davar can be but from the PDG source they are naming their method least squares but always use the symbol $\chi^2$ for the minimization function.  Damn sloppy physicists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question one can start from the **weighted least squared**, which can be summarized in "weighting" every summand of the least square sum by the inverse of variance of the the point given by
\begin{equation}
  w_i = \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}.
\end{equation}
The least square sum can then be written as:
\begin{equation}
  \chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\left(y_i-\mu(x_i; \boldsymbol{\theta})\right)^2}{\sigma^2}.
\end{equation}
Regarding the formula in question (in matrix form, with the covariance matrix V):
\begin{equation}
    \chi^2 (\boldsymbol\theta) = (\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol\mu(\boldsymbol \theta))^T V^{-1}(\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol\mu(\boldsymbol \theta)),
\end{equation}
one notices that the covariance matrix V is a symmetric matrix, meaning that we can diagonalize it as
\begin{equation}
  D = P^{-1} C P, \quad \text{with} \quad D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 &  & \\  & \lambda_2 &  \\ &&\ddots & \\ &&& \lambda_N}.
\end{equation}
The $1/\lambda_i$ (we have to invert D) can then be interpreted as the "weights". 
In the case of a data with zero covariance we initially get a diagonal covariance matrix V
\begin{equation}
 V = \pmatrix{\sigma^2_1 &  & \\  & \sigma^2_2 &  \\ &&\ddots & \\ &&& \sigma^2_N},
\end{equation}
which recovers the method of *weighted least squared*. Otherways one deals with the more general form, the **Generalized Least Squares** method, which additionally accounts for **non-zero covariances**.